# Documenting a Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, documentation-generation, comments

I have inherited a sql server that is used for generating reports, text file outputs and fixed width files for use and import into other systems.

The developer (X) did not document or comment a single bit of code. X also used stored procedures, views, SSIS, SQLCMD and every combination in between. X also created multiple databases across the environment to save these views, SPs etc. So we have situations where a SP is opening a view which opens another view that calls SQLCMD at the end of it. Lots of use of RTRIM, REPLACE, STR, CONVERT...I'm sure you get the picture... (thats the background).

I am wanting ideas on the best way to approach, correct and document this environment so that it can be supported.

I've started following the query trail, copying the queries into one text file and commenting in Notepad++ with formatting...then trying to consolidate the query to be efficient and documented.

Are there any less time consuming options?
I'm sure many DBA's have gone through this, what is the recommended approach?

PS. Apology for the long post

Comment: If you want to automate the creation of documentation of database objects, then try RED GATE tools. If this is a one time job, then you can use the trial version. I generated a few nice professional looking docs sometimes. HTH.

Answer (score 3):

> PS. Apology for the long post

Fugetaboutit, our sympathy for your plight severely mitigates any irritation over a long post (and it wasn't all that long).

There may be some tools available to help you automate the process to some extent. Definitely start with some ER diagrams to help you visualize what you have.

However, of particular concern in your description of the system. It sounds like developer X may have also modeled the system and did just as impressive a job as designing the code. That's my impression when you mentioned "Lots of use of RTRIM, REPLACE, STR, CONVERT..." and the funky views. Sounds like a system designed by a developer.

I would recommend that you document the system only to the point where you have a good idea of what is going on (or what should be going on). Then start a process of database refactoring to get the system in decent shape. This will be a time-consuming operation (and somewhat expensive) but if this is an important system then it will be well worth it. Try to convince management that the time and expense would be front-loaded and will end up saving time and money in the long run. Good luck with that. Management can be notoriously short sighted about such things.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer per se, but something that should help:

```
DECLARE @SearchText varchar(100)
SET @SearchText = 'myTable'

SELECT
   schema_name(ob.schema_id)  SchemaName
  ,ob.name
  ,ob.type_desc
  ,len(mo.definition) CodeLength
  --,mo.definition
 from sys.sql_modules mo
  inner join .sys.objects ob
   on ob.object_id = mo.object_id
 where mo.definition like '%' + @SearchText + '%'
 order by
   case schema_name(ob.schema_id)
     when 'dbo' then 'A'
     else 'B' + str(ob.schema_id, 10)
   end
  ,ob.type_desc
  ,ob.name
```

This will produce a list of all "code-based objects" (procedures, views, triggers, but not synonyms or constraints) that contain the text in @SearchText in the current database.  You'll still have to go into the object to find out how it's used (as in, a SELECT against a table or just a reference to the table in a comment*), but it could save you a lot of time, particularly if you start with tables and "dig out", looking for all views, procs, etc. that reference that table... then all objects that reference them... and so on.

(* Yes, the current code doesn't have comments, but your revisions will, so bear this in mind.)

Answer (score 0):

Having to rewrite many non-documented legacy applications, I have had to create documentation similar to what you are describing.  I usually break down the application documentation into categories.

1) Document the Database Tables and Relationships between tables (ER Diagrams)

2) Document the SQL Queries

3) Document the Stored Procedures and Triggers

4) Document the application code

5) Document the UI - showing screenshots of the major components

6) Document primary Use Cases using a UML Drawing tool

7) Document the hardware environment, database utilities, user accounts, OS

http://www.yazooconsulting.com/products.html

Comment: How does the link help the OP with regards to reducing the amount of time required to document their DB? This just seems to be an advert for design and reporting tools.